# Will I be able to use NDSolve, and then how

Tags: differential-equations, physics

So I am completely new to Mathematica, so sorry if this is a dumb question.

I have a set of 3 coupled nonlinear differential equations.  They are (a,b,c,D,L constants):
$$mx''=Dx'\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2+z'^2}+L(az'-by')$$
$$my''=Dy'\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2+z'^2}+L(bx'-cz')$$
$$mz''=Dz'\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2+z'^2}+L(cy'-ax')$$
And I have initial conditions for $x,y,z,x',y',z'$

Will I be able to solve this for x,y,z?  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I am  confused on the syntax as well.  [eqns, u, {t, tmin, tmax}] is in the documentation.  So how do I solve for 3 equations?

Comment: Follow Nasser's lead: write your equations (ODEs and ICs) in terms of `x[t],y[t],z[t]`, and supply them to `NDSolve` after specifying the values of the constants (you can use a replacement rule like `eqs /. {m->1, D->2, L->1, a->.3, b->.2,c->.5}` inside `NDSolve`. Then you will obtain your solution in the form of a list of three interpolating functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example:

```
ClearAll[t, x, y, z];
parms = {d -> 1, L1 -> 10, a -> 5, b -> 99, c -> 8, m -> 100};
term = Sqrt[x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2 + z'[t]^2];
eq1 = m x''[t] == d x'[t] term + L1 (a z'[t] - b y'[t]);
eq2 = m y''[t] == d y'[t] term + L1 (b z'[t] - c y'[t]);
eq3 = m z''[t] == d z'[t] term + L1 (c z'[t] - a y'[t]);
ic1 = {x'[0] == 0, x[0] == 1};
ic2 = {y'[0] == 2, y[0] == 3};
ic3 = {z'[0] == 0, z[0] == 1};
```

Now call NDSolve

```
 sol = NDSolve[{eq1, eq2, eq3, ic1, ic2, ic3} /. parms, {x[t], y[t],z[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now can plot the solution, say

```
  Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or the 3 solutions in one plot (can use legends to label them, etc....)

```
 Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

ParameterPlot3D per request

```
 ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 10}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, .5, .5}, AxesLabel -> {"x[t]", "y[t]", "z[t]"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: A 3D  parametric plot would be more appealing :-)

Comment: How would that work?  This is for the trajectory of a baseball, so 1 plot would be amazing

Comment: @yankeefan11 Please look up [ParametricPlot3D](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html) in the docs.

Comment: @Peltio, add p3D, is this what you had in mind?

Comment: @Nasser Yep, that's it. Trajectory in 3D space.